# Change cPanel MySQL User maximum character value

Tags: mysql, cpanel

We are moving our websites to a new server. And in the process, we have found that our current version of cPanel 11.24 doesn't have a maximum number of characters for a MySQL Database Username, like cPanel 11.25 does (it's set to 7). However, we have MySQL users whose names are longer than 7 characters.

1. Will something disastrous happen if we upgrade cPanel on our current server?
2. How can I change this setting in the new version of cPanel / WHM?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Every cPanel server should have this length limit enforced regardless of version, since MySQL itself has a limit of 16 characters for a username.  Thus, when you create a MySQL user for the cPanel user, you end up with 7 characters to spare:  unixuser_1234567

Citation for MySQL 16 character max: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/user-names.html